# What the functionality is called which is used while logging out of Google account?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, logout

When we want to log-out from the google/gmail account, we click on the profile picture displayed at the right most of the Google bar. The scenario with the pop-up is shown in below figure.

[image]

What does this functionality called in jQuery, HTML? I think it's not a modal pop-up as it's not appearing on the existing content of a page and background content is non-clickable. Also it can't be called as tool-tip as it's not showing up on mouse hover, we need to click on profile picture to see the log out button. So what does it called?

I'm asking this thing curiously because I need to implement same functionality in my website. That is when user clicks on specific text the pop-up/tool-tip(for now I'm using these words for your understanding only, may be I'm using wrong words). As I don't know the exact word for this functionality I'm not able to find out such jQuery plugin on internet which would behave the same way.

One more thing is that I want to use a form in this pop-up/tool-tip which would be submitted to PHP using AJAX.

Comment: I'd suggest redacting your personal information as well....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popover!

Example API from a popular CSS/JS toolkit:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers